# git log with date range (--after/--before) failing to list all commits

Tags: git, linux-kernel

Trying to understand why git log with specified date range is not showing commits and are definitely there. I'm trying to parse commits from linux-kernel mailing list as stored in git at lore.kernel.org.

For example in attempting to get commits from Aug 23 2021, I attempt the following

```
$ git clone https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/10
$ cd 10
$ git log --pretty='%H - %cd' | grep "Aug 23"
af52111eb7a493c207ce60b058bdab7348064add - Mon Aug 23 02:59:56 2021 +0000
9fcd26f3a182d467faf3f26d278a8af2cc0f8965 - Mon Aug 23 02:48:16 2021 +0000
1c09199280cdf70622e33282e14c99bfe41320e1 - Mon Aug 23 02:45:28 2021 +0000
55ebe507b4300d8f51572fab73f5bd49041017ed - Mon Aug 23 02:45:11 2021 +0000
7bd7315d4274b2703ee915945d64523aee469b19 - Mon Aug 23 02:41:28 2021 +0000
59cca96255614715f767ee22820c58eb2e90dd50 - Mon Aug 23 02:40:18 2021 +0000
3ace7b418cfe58f1c7aaa7fad5b2a25dfd211018 - Mon Aug 23 02:39:40 2021 +0000
abdd2cd79bcd4f2487055aa277e39fe6a4f59411 - Mon Aug 23 02:29:40 2021 +0000
3946b9a8b03e5b87119800dde0e40346a487b496 - Mon Aug 23 02:29:04 2021 +0000
b9ee71561b8ee7ad4fb2e7cfa197bbab26a8a585 - Mon Aug 23 02:24:13 2021 +0000
3025a71ed7f4ab8ea0775145529134b6be603b0e - Mon Aug 23 02:19:36 2021 +0000
65ef4bf88396f64743bc46323afc5170e07b935c - Mon Aug 23 02:14:13 2021 +0000
eb15ca44beccd69f38c349cfa0837444d153ee80 - Mon Aug 23 02:12:24 2021 +0000
87c78206da57d42d3d1e22632d12670021b75965 - Mon Aug 23 02:09:43 2021 +0000
2694ff54997e1bc79eae14b6343da47dab1bd10b - Mon Aug 23 02:08:09 2021 +0000
27a99205d60ef612b982108f18ff1d924b100712 - Mon Aug 23 02:06:14 2021 +0000
0a6aabe065d9a538f3a0a62549b938c74d86d499 - Mon Aug 23 02:05:18 2021 +0000
294af22adb00ddc9befe417563437d0bcd760e31 - Mon Aug 23 02:03:12 2021 +0000
b90ee1d5b75cd7d17a8b4bf9f890d761f17f6dc8 - Mon Aug 23 02:02:13 2021 +0000
...

$ git log --pretty='%H - %cd' | grep "Aug 23" | wc -l
1107
```

This clearly shows there were 1107 commits on Aug 23 2021.
However if I specify I only want to see  these commits via --after and --before commands I get nothing back, as follows:

```
$ git log --pretty='%H - %cd' --after='2021-08-22 23:59:59' --before='2021-08-24 00:00:00'
```

In actual fact, no matter what date I use in --after argument I never get to see the commits from Aug 23, one only gets to see them if --after is ommitted completely:

```
$ git log --pretty='%H - %cd' --after='2000-01-01 23:59:59' | grep "Aug 23" | wc -l
0
```

Even if I specify all commits after Aug 01, 2021, I only see commits from Aug 27, 26, and 25.

Git version being used is 2.27.0.

Why is `git log` failing to list these commits using --after argument ?

Comment: Someone introduced a bug in the date code recently. I *think* it's fixed in the most recent Git versions. There may still be some shortcut code that's overly aggressive in some cases but that isn't supposed to kick in unless there's a six-month discrepancy. (I was going to note that `--after` uses committer date while log normally shows author date, but you used `%cd` here to get committer date, so that's not it.) Not sure which Git versions have which bugs here, but worth checking with a later one.

Comment: Just downloaded and built 2.33.0 and it is exhibiting the exact same issue.
Also tried an older version 2.18 and also same issue is displayed. I wonder could this be git repo specific ?

Comment: Might be, especially if you do have a commit that exceeds that six-month thing. If the repo is available to the general public, you could send a bug report to the Git mailing list...

Comment: This is definitely public git repo, and in testing some other linux-kernel repositories they don't appear to be exhibiting the same issues. As such I actually think it might be unique to this specific git repo : https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/10

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, this turns out to be a specific issue with this repo, and how git log operates.

Git log traverses from HEAD down the commit chain. If the CommitDate falls within the range specified by --after/--before then the commit is printed.

When the first commit with a CommitDate older than --after, git log simply exits, as git log presumes commits are added to git in chronological order. However this is not the case now with this repo.

On 25-Aug-2021, an email originally sent by Linus 30 years ago on 25-Aug-1991, was resent to commemorate that milestone.

This email had an AuthorDate of 25-Aug-1991, and as lore I believe uses "git fast-import" the CommitDate for the commit was set to the AuthorDate e.g. 25-Aug-1991.

This commit has sha a3d6603dc016, and if we look at the commits on either side of this commit we can see the lack of chronological order for CommitDate and AuthorDate

Sha's
fdd99a4a1672 -> a3d6603dc016 -> d24a05a379ff

CommitDate:
"Wed Aug 25 10:41:18 2021" -> "Sun Aug 25 13:57:08 1991" -> "Wed Aug 25 10:46:34 2021"

Git log is expecting this dates to be in chronological order, however as you can see they are not.

Now would one consider this a git bug ? Should git be able to handle this ?

Comment: That looks like a candidate for that six-month thing I was talking about. I think (vague memory from looking at this long ago) that Git tries to accommodate "slightly out of chronological order" commits, so that the traversal continues as long as the committer date is not *too* far out of the range, but if there's a 1991 date, that's so far out of range that Git just stops there. Is that a bug? I'd say yes: Git should keep going for at least a few more commits, or—now that there's the new commit graph code—use the "adjusted" date stamp.